# Как "аз" превратилось в Я?

Tags: этимология

Подумалось: раньше о себе говорили "аз", сейчас - "я". С первого места алфавита местоимение переместилось на последнее. А как и когда это случилось?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Яzz**

У вас немного "хронометрия" страдает. В ***русском*** "АЗЪ" сразу превратилось в ЯЗЪ, "АЗъ" - это вариант старославянский, Какое-то время АЗЪ и ЯЗЪ существовали параллельно, потом, когда действие ЗОС сильно ослабело, АЗ вторично вытеснил ЯЗ, произошло это много позже падения редуцированных.

Т.е. если изобразить на шкале времени:

***АЗЪ>ЯЗЪ>(ЯЗЪ,Я)>(ЯЗЪ/АЗЪ,Я)>(АЗЪ,Я)>Я.***

Вариант "Я" встречается уже в памятниках XI века, а церковнославянский АЗЪ окончательно вытеснил ЯЗЪ только в XIV-XV веках и просуществовал так в качестве формы высокого стиля аж до Пушкина, да и потом не был окончательно потерян.

Answer (score 3):

Аз, буква, до сих пор открывает алфавит, только имя сменила. Я стала замыкать алфавит после реформы 1918 года, до этого крайней буквой была "ижица".

Если говорить про личное местоимение,  то звук [j] добавился из-за того, что в языке был период когда в языке был закон отсутствия открытых слогов. [з] после падения редуцированных гласных тоже отпала и из "аз" получилось "я".