# Оригинальный текст "Слова о полку Игореве"

Tags: литература, история, славянизмы

[Здесь](http://az.lib.ru/z/zhukowskij_w_a/text_0126.shtml), как понимаю, перевод старославянского?

"[Аз](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/24493/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b0%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%af) есмь царь" — это оригинал?

Интересно увидеть больше оригинальных текстов.

Comment: [Слово о пълку Игоревѣ, Игоря сына Святъславля, внука Ольгова](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83_%D0%98%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82)

Comment: Да это текст 200-летней давности. Существует ли тексты тысячилетней давности?

Comment: @user1855805 "Слово.." описывает события 1185 г. Тысячу лет назад этого произведения ещё не было. С того времени оригиналы остались только на берестяных грамотах, остальное более или менее древние списки.

Answer (score 2):

Оригинальное "Слово о полку Игореве" сгорело во время пожара в Москве 1812 г. До нас дошёл только перевод.

Comment: В 1812 году сгорел, конечно, не оригинал, а старейший из известных списков, скорее всего, 17-го века, с большим количеством ошибок переписчиков. С этого списка сохранилось две полные копии, обе со своими ошибками, и несколько переводов. Все современные издания - это результат реконструкции на основании этих источников и современных знаний о древнерусском языке. [В википедии](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Слово_о_полку_Игореве) есть подробное изложение и ссылки.